# How does this simplification in expectation value algebra work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

We have a Hamiltonian of form:

$$\hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + \hat{H}_1$$

Where $\hat{H}_1$ is a time dependent perturbation which can be written as:

$$\hat{H}_1(t) = - \hat{A}F(t)$$

Now $B$ is another observable. The change in the expectation value $\langle B\rangle$ due to the perturbation term is given by:

$$\Delta\langle B\rangle = \beta F\big(\langle AB\rangle_o - \langle A\rangle_o\langle B\rangle_o\big)$$

I don't have any confusion in the derivations leading up to this point. But in the next step the author writes:

$$\Delta\langle B\rangle = \beta F \langle\delta A \delta B\rangle_o$$

So my confusion is why is

$$\big(\langle AB\rangle_o - \langle A\rangle_o\langle B\rangle_o \big) = \langle\delta A \delta B\rangle_o$$

and what do $\delta A$ and $\delta B$ signify?

Comment: Not really relevant for what you're actually asking, but what is $\beta$ here?

Comment: it is (KT)^(-1) where K is Boltzmann constant and T is the temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\delta A = A - \langle A \rangle_o$, and similar for B. If you substitute this into the RHS and multiply out, you'll get the LHS.